# Constructing IV in certain condition and can you check whether my answer is okay or not?

Tags: econometrics, instrumental-variables, endogeneity

I have the following regression: $$
score_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 course_i + u_i.$$
(in case, the variables are not obvious, $score_i$ is the exam score and $course_i$ is taking a preparatory course, so it is a binary variable)

As I mentioned in the question, the certain condition is that $20\%$ students do not have to pay for a preparatory course somehow and I need to construct IV for $course_i$ by using this information (tuition waiver).

Here is my answer, since there is tuition waiver (for $20\%$ of students), when we consider parental income (as IV for $course_i$) has less effect on $score_i$, the parental income is a good IV for $course_i$.

What I am not sure is that since still $80\%$ of students have to pay for a preparatory course, there are likely several ways that it could affect on $score_i$. So parental income cannot be a good IV.

If so, what would be a good IV in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to use parental income as an instrument for taking the course, the identifying assumption would be that income only alters the score through the course. That seems unlikely to hold, since richer parents can also hire tutors to boost scores. Parental income can reflect cognitive ability, which could be inherited or effect the child's environment through resources like books, which can alter scores as well.

I wonder if there is a way to recast this problem as a fuzzy regression discontinuity one, which is a kind of IV. There are a few examples [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A7071+fuzzy+RD) that explain the approach.